# Uploading local file to Google Cloud storage gives error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file to Google cloud storage but it is throwing exception.

This is my code:-

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendFileToGcs();
    }

    private static void sendFileToGcs()
    {
           GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
          .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
          .retryMaxAttempts(10)
          .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
          .build());
          try{
              GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
              GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("my-bucket", "myFile");
              GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
              outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
              File file = new File("audio.mp3");

              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
              InputStream is = fis;

              copy(is, Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
              fis.close();
          }catch(IOException e){}
          while(true){}

    }

    private static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
         final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
            try {
              byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
              int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
              while (bytesRead != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
              }
            } finally {
              input.close();
              output.close();
            }
          }

}
```

Exception details:-

```
> Aug 02, 2016 3:41:01 PM
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry INFO:
> RetryHelper(14.86 ms, 1 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #1 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 12 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(59.97 ms, 2 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #2 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 16 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(77.05 ms, 3 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #3 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 32 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(110.4 ms, 4 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #4 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 82 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(193.5 ms, 5 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #5 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 159 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(353.7 ms, 6 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #6 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 394 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:01 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(750.2 ms, 7 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #7 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 640 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:02 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(1.393 s, 8 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #8 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 1547 ms Aug 02, 2016
> 3:41:04 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
> INFO: RetryHelper(2.941 s, 9 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Attempt #9 failed [java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 2694 ms Exception in
> thread "main"
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetriesExhaustedException:
> RetryHelper(5.637 s, 10 attempts,
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1de0aca6):
> Too many failures, giving up  at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:127)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
>   at MainClass.sendApkToFirebase(MainClass.java:33)   at
> MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:186)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.access$000(LocalRawGcsService.java:109)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.ensureInitialized(LocalRawGcsService.java:194)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:249)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:92)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:74)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
>   ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.<init>(LocalRawGcsService.java:123)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:184)
>   ... 12 more
```

Comment: I have the exact same error right now.  If I find a solution I will let you know.

Comment: That would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running that code in App Engine? According to https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-stackoverflow/mVl-gpyIZdY/QZPvGkWeHgAJ that library is intended to be used there (or with the App development center).